# MenuItem must be inside a form element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Why Show Error in my Application.

```
javax.faces.FacesException: MenuItem must be inside a form element
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:161)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.MenuRenderer.encodeElements(MenuRenderer.java:84)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.MenuRenderer.encodeSubmenu(MenuRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.MenuRenderer.encodeElements(MenuRenderer.java:88)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.MenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(MenuRenderer.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:105)
.......................
```

Model Class Here ......

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml

Comment: show your jsp code as well

Comment: Search before you ask such a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a form on your jsp/xhtml pages.

Wrap your menu item in a `<h:form>` tag